# Script for converting to e+ in javascript

Tags: javascript, scientific-notation

```
function eFinder(number) {
    let c = Math.round(number);
    let a = c.toString().length - 1;
    let b = number.toString().charAt(0);
    return `${b}e+${a}`;
}
```

`eFinder(100);` would return 1e+2.
This basically converts any number put in eFinder(); to scientific notation.

Answer (score 4):

Why do you want to implement it by yourself while this is part of JavaScript? Just use [`Number.prototype.toExponential()`](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Number/toExponential)

```js
const number = 100;
console.log(number.toExponential());
```